# replace missing with mode for factor column and mean for numeric column in r

Tags: r, replace, mean, missing-data, mode

I have the following data frame named as "train". columns bflag and zfactor are factor and the other 2 columns are numeric. I want to replace missing values of the factor columns with mode and the missing values of numeric variables with mean in the same data frame. How i can do this in R?

```
ID   bflag  vcount zfactor vnumber
1     0       12      1       12
2     1       NA      0       8
3     0       3       0       9
4     1       13      0       NA
5     1       2       1       2
6     NA      10      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can iterate over the columns and use a simple `if` statement.  We will have to define a function for the mode, since base R does not provide one.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x)) replace(x, is.na(x), Mode(na.omit(x)))
    else if(is.numeric(x)) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
    else x
})

df
#   ID bflag vcount zfactor vnumber
# 1  1     0     12       1   12.00
# 2  2     1      8       0    8.00
# 3  3     0      3       0    9.00
# 4  4     1     13       0    7.75
# 5  5     1      2       1    2.00
# 6  6     1     10       0    7.75
```

Data and `Mode` function:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID   bflag  vcount zfactor vnumber
1     0       12      1       12
2     1       NA      0       8
3     0       3       0       9
4     1       13      0       NA
5     1       2       1       2
6     NA      10      NA      NA", 
colClasses = rep(c("numeric", "factor"), length.out=5), 
header = TRUE)

Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

`Mode` borrowed from [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode/8189441#8189441)

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. I was struggling to find a way to calculate mode after implementing `mean` but your answer sorted out my problem. I have referred you in my answer, hope you dont mind.

Comment: @MKR - no problem at all :)

Answer (score 3):

The `dplyr::mutate_if` will help to decide type of column and function/operation `(mode/mean)` that is needed for that column. The solution will be:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace(.,is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(replace(.,is.na(.), Mode(na.omit(.)))))

#   ID bflag vcount zfactor vnumber
# 1  1     0     12       1   12.00
# 2  2     1      8       0    8.00
# 3  3     0      3       0    9.00
# 4  4     1     13       0    7.75
# 5  5     1      2       1    2.00
# 6  6     1     10       0    7.75
```

**Note:** The `Mode` function has been taken from `@RichScriven` answer. Link for `Mode` function is at ([Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode/8189441#8189441))

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```